# Read browser window size using JavaScript and then pass it to C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser

I would like to do the following

I need to generate n number of tabs bassed on Screen Resolution. For example, if screen resolution is 800x600, I want to generate 4 tabs using C#. If it is 1024x764, then 10 tabs.

I know I can get the height and width using `screen.width` and `screen.height` using `JavaScript`. I wrote it on the `onload()` of body and set two hidden fields to get the value in server side.

The issue is that, the server side code will execute first and JavaScript code will be executed. Am I right ? Due to this, I can not get the correct value in hidden fields when I needed. But when I use alert() in `JavaScript` code it shows the correct resolution.

How can I get the correct resolution in server side code?

Answer (score 1):

Look for a cookie containing the screen width on the server.  If the cookie doesn't exist send back a page that creates the cookie and does a redirect to the original url.  When the cookie is available, use the value for the width to determine how many tabs to generate.  See here for a tutorial on browser-side cookie management: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html or use the jQuery [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) if using jQuery already.  You'll need to generate a new cookie value whenever the browser is resized.

Now that you have a basic outline for how to do it, let me say that I think it's better to build the tabbed interface so that it works with the same number of tabs regardless of screen width.  Check out how jQuery UI tabs works by floating each tab left so that if there isn't enough screen to display them all on one line, it flows to another line (and so on).

Answer (score 1):

This helped me `createCookie("cookieScreenWidth", screen.width, 1);` where createCookie(...) is a user defined function. I wrote the code in the login page.

So I could retrieve the vale in my page as (using C#) 
`Request.Cookies.Get("cookieScreenWidth").Value`

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the resolution after a full round-trip (server serves a page, javascript reads the values, browser passes values to server).

This can be done through AJAX, or through posting a form, cookies or through the URL. Many different ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but you could capture the javascript variables in one 'stub' page and then forward to an asp page, with the screen res as parameters, using Request.Params on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Get the window diamensions in javascript and pass that to a server page using ajax, Get the response (HTML for 4 tab/ HTML for 10 tab) from that page now and load to the initial page